# Access package-private variables using reserved package name

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I was studying the source code of [`java.util.HashMap`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/HashMap.java.htm) and I wanted to see how well the hashcode function distributes the key's in the internal array of `Entry`'s(*which is a package private variable*).So I made a package named `java.util` in my project just to check weather I can fool the compiler to think it's the same package.Surprisingly it worked and I wrote the following code:

```
package java.util;

public class HashMapExt<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMapExt<Integer, String> mp = new HashMapExt<Integer, String>();
        mp.put(1, "Hello");
        mp.put(2, "Map");
        mp.put(3, "Extention");
        mp.printData();
    }

    void printData() {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(table));
    }
}
```

It compiled successfully but while running it gave an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Now the question is, is it possible to change the default security model so that I can access the internal variable `table` or is there any other alternative (*maybe  by using reflection*) ?

Answer (score 6):

Even if there is an option to have your class in the `java.util` package (like replacing the core jar or defining your custom class loader for example), you'd better use reflection. It is simple and straightforward:

```
Field tableField = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("table");
tableField.setAccessible(true);
Map.Entry[] entries = (Map.Entry[]) tableField.get(yourMap);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try either prepending your jar in the classpath or <strike>by using an endorsed directory</strike>.

The former:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:youJarHere.jar  .....
```

And the effect is, to load first the classes you have in yourJar, even overriding core classes.

<strike>The later form is to place in your `$JAVA_HOME/lib/endorsed` directory the classes/jars, it has a similar effect.</strike>

I haven't used any of these for a couple of years, but I used them once to replace a core class ( something in the CORBA package or something like that ).

Give it a try and let us know if it worked.

Here some links:

http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2010/02/replacing-and-patching-java-application-and-core-classes/

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/

Comment: This is a bit confusing.What is an endorsed directory ?

Comment: From the link: *The Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism provides a means whereby later versions of classes and interfaces that implement Endorsed Standards or Standalone Technologies may be incorporated into the Java Platform.*  It looks like `java.util` is not suitable for this mechanism though. I'll update the answer