# Java data structure

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, guava

I need some data structure that I can build from standard collections or using guava. So it should be mutable `Map<Enum, V>`.  Where `V` is pretty interesting structure.

`V` requirements:

- mutable
- sorted by comparator (with allowing elements such as compare(a, b) == 0) - these is need for iterations
- set (there is no such `a` and `b`, that `a.equals(b) == true`)  - optional

extra optional requirement to map

- keys should be iterated by their natural order

now it's  `HashMap<SomeEnum, LinkedList<Entity>>` with different stuff like `collections.sort()` in the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### A Sample implementation

Here is a [Guava Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementation of the class you need:

First the drawback: it will have to reside in package `com.google.common.collect`. The makers of guava have in their infinite wisdom made `AbstractSortedSetMultimap` package scoped.

I will use this `enum` in all my examples:

```
public enum Color{
    RED, BLUE, GREEN
};
```

### Constructing the Class

There are six constructors:

- Empty (Uses a `HashMap` and natural ordering for values)

  ```
  SortedSetMultimap<Color,String> simple = 
      new EnumValueSortMultiMap<Color, String>();
  ```
- with a `Comparator(V)` (Uses a `HashMap<K,SortedSet<V>>` with the supplied comparator for the values)

  ```
  SortedSetMultimap<Color,String> inreverse =
      new EnumValueSortMultiMap<Color, String>(
          Ordering.natural().reverse()
      );
  ```
- with a `Map<K,SortedSet<V>>` (use this if you want to sort keys, pass in a `SortedMap` implementation)

  ```
  SortedSetMultimap<Color,String> withSortedKeys = 
      new EnumValueSortMultiMap<Color, String>(
          new TreeMap<Color, Collection<String>>()
      );
  ```
- with a `Map<K,SortedSet<V>>` and a `Comparator<V>` (same as above, but values are sorted using custom comparator)

  ```
  SortedSetMultimap<Color,String> reverseWithSortedKeys = 
      new EnumValueSortMultiMap<Color, String>(
          new TreeMap<Color, Collection<String>>(),
          Ordering.natural().reverse()
      );
  ```
- with a `Class<K extends Enum<K>>` (uses an `EnumMap` internally for higher efficiency, natural ordering for values)

  ```
  SortedSetMultimap<Color,String> withEnumMap =
      new EnumValueSortMultiMap<Color, String>(
          Color.class
      );
  ```
- with a `Class<K extends Enum<K>>` and a `Comparator<V>`  (same as above, but values are sorted using custom comparator)

  ```
  SortedSetMultimap<Color,String> reverseWithEnumMap =
      new EnumValueSortMultiMap<Color, String>(
          Color.class, Ordering.natural().reverse()
      );
  ```

### Source Code

Here's the class:

```
package com.google.common.collect;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class EnumValueSortMultiMap<K extends Enum<K>,
    V extends Comparable<? super V>>
    extends AbstractSortedSetMultimap<K, V>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5359491222446743952L;

    private Comparator<? super V> comparator;
    private Class<K> enumType;

    public EnumValueSortMultiMap(){
        this(new HashMap<K, Collection<V>>());
    }

    public EnumValueSortMultiMap(final Comparator<? super V> comparator){
        this(new HashMap<K, Collection<V>>(), comparator);
    }

    public EnumValueSortMultiMap(final Map<K, Collection<V>> map){
        this(map, Ordering.natural());
    }

    public EnumValueSortMultiMap(final Map<K, Collection<V>> map,
        final Comparator<? super V> comparator){
        super(map);
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public EnumValueSortMultiMap(final Class<K> enumClass,
        final Comparator<? super V> comparator){
        this(new EnumMap<K, Collection<V>>(enumClass), comparator);
    }

    public EnumValueSortMultiMap(final Class<K> enumClass){
        this(new EnumMap<K, Collection<V>>(enumClass));
    }

    @Override
    Map<K, Collection<V>> backingMap(){
        return new EnumMap<K, Collection<V>>(enumType);
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<? super V> valueComparator(){
        return comparator;
    }

    @Override
    SortedSet<V> createCollection(){
        return new TreeSet<V>(comparator);
    }

}
```

---

### Other ways to do it

**UPDATE:** I guess the proper Guava way to do it would have been something like this (it uses the `SortedArrayList` class I wrote [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344246/comparator-and-equals/4344324#4344324)):

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>, V> Multimap<E, V> getMap(
    final Class<E> clz){

    return Multimaps.newListMultimap(
        Maps.<E, Collection<V>> newEnumMap(clz),
        new Supplier<List<V>>(){
            @Override
            public List<V> get(){
                return new SortedArrayList<V>();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Probably, I will use it. It's will be perfect if after this answer Kewin'll change AbstractSortedSetMultimap's scope)

Comment: I guess they will eventually. My guess is that they haven't committed themselves to the API yet, so they are only exposing implementation classes.

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer, I hope it will be.

Comment: @Stas:If they don't change the scope you can make a package named 'com.google.common.collect' in your project and add the class.I tried it and it's working for me.

Comment: @Emil it works, yes, but it's also a butt-ugly solution. And I'm pretty sure it relies on non-guaranteed classloader behaviors (I would guess a classloader is free to cache physical locations of packages and that mechanism would break if the package exists in multiple places. But I'm not sure about this)

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer:                                               [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224760/access-package-private-variables-using-reserved-package-name) on this subject.

Comment: @Emil thanks, but that won't help in this case (there's no way to access a super class in a class definition via reflection, and the endorsed dir approach is very tedious)

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer: No that's not what i meant .Just check the link's in the second answer on how to patch api's .Not that we should use it just for your info.

Comment: @Stas have a look at my updated answer. Things are apparently a lot easier than I thought...

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer: Thanks. I should add more +1 )

Comment: @Stas Thanks for the bounty! That really wasn't necessary though :-)

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer, you've done big job. So it's thanks for you)

Answer (score 6):

If an extra class is too much, you maybe want to use the factory methods of the class [`Multimaps`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html).

```
SortedSetMultimap<Color, Entity> set = Multimaps.newSortedSetMultimap(
    new HashMap<Enum, Collection<Entity>>(), 
    new Supplier<TreeSet<Entity>>() {
        @Override
        public TreeSet<Entity> get() {
            return new TreeSet<Entity>(new Comparator<Entity>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Entity o1, Entity o2) {
                    //TODO implement
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Very nicely summarized.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [EnumMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) instead of the current `HashMap`. `EnumMap`s are more efficient for enum keys. In guava check [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) [[examples](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/09/26/google-collections/)].

Comment: `EnumMap` is a good idea (+1), but the problem is that that does not allow for an empty constructor. The enum class is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need an collection implementation V which is used this way: HashMap<SomeEnum, V>. The above stated requirements affect V (not Entity). Right?

I think a [link TreeSet<E>](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) should fullfill your requirents:

- TreeSet implements the Set interface
- Sorted by natural order or custom Comparator
- Elements can be added and removed

Comment: Yeah. I implement it first with it) But TreeSet can't contains such elements with `compare(a, b) == 0`.