# Comparator and equals()

Tags: java, equals, comparator, treeset

Suppose I need `TreeSet` with elements sorted with some domain logic. By this logic it doesn't matter order of some elements that doesn't equal so compare method can return 0, but in this case I couldn't put them in `TreeSet`.

So, question: what disadvantages I'll have from code like this:

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>{}
new TreeSet<Foo>(new Comparator<Foo>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
        int res = o1.compareTo(o2);
        if(res == 0 || !o1.equals(o2)){
            return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();
        }
        return res;
    }
});
```

**Update**:

Ok. If it should always be a consistency between the methods `equals()`, `hashcode()` and `compareTo()`, as @S.P.Floyd - seanizer and others said.
If it would be better or even good if I'll remove `Comparable` interface and move this logic in `Comparator` (I can do it without broken encapsulation)? So it will be:

```
class Foo{}
new TreeSet<Foo>(new Comparator<Foo>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
        //some logic start
        if(strictliBigger(o1, o2)){ return 1;}
        if(strictliBigger(o2, o1)){ return -1;}
        //some logic end
        if(res == 0 || !o1.equals(o2)){
            return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();
        }
        return res;
    }
});
```

**Update 2**:

Would `System.identityHashCode(x)` be better than `hashCode()` if I don't need stable sort?

Comment: So, you want to write your own comparator to structure ordering in your treeset?

Comment: one of those returns after `strictliBigger` should be -1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While this might work, it is far from being a best practice.

From the [SortedSet docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html):

> **Note that the ordering** maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) **must be consistent with equals if the sorted set is to correctly implement the Set interface**. (See the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface or [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted set performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted set, equal. The behavior of a sorted set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

For objects that implement `Comparable`, there should always be a consistency between the methods `equals()`, `hashcode()` and `compareTo()`.

---

I'm afraid a `SortedSet` is just not what you want, nor will a Guava `MultiSet` be adequate (because it will not let you independently retrieve multiple equal items). I think what you need is a `SortedList`. There is no such beast that I know of (maybe in commons-collections, but those are a bit on the legacy side), so I implemented one for you using Guava's ForwardingList as a base class. In short: this List delegates almost everything to an `ArrayList` it uses internally, but it uses `Collections.binarySearch()` in it's `add()` method to find the right insertion position and it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` on all optional methods of the `List` and `ListIterator` interfaces that add or set values at a given position.

The Constructors are identical to those of [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), but for each of them there is also a second version with a custom `Comparator`. If you don't use a custom Comparator, your list elements need to implement `Comparable` or `RuntimeException`s will occur during sorting.

```
public class SortedArrayList<E> extends ForwardingList<E> implements
    RandomAccess{

    private final class ListIteratorImpl extends ForwardingListIterator<E>{
        private final int start;
        public ListIteratorImpl(final int start){
            this.start = start;
        }

        @Override
        public void set(E element){throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}

        @Override
        public void add(E element){throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}

        @Override
        protected ListIterator<E> delegate(){return inner.listIterator(start);};

    }

    private Comparator<? super E> comparator;

    private List<E> inner;

    public SortedArrayList(){this(null, null, null);}

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private SortedArrayList(
        final List<E> existing,
        final Collection<? extends E> values,
        final Comparator<? super E> comparator
    ){
        this.comparator =
            (Comparator<? super E>)
               (comparator == null
                   ? Ordering.natural()
                   : comparator   );
        inner = (
            existing == null
                ? (values == null
                      ? new ArrayList<E>(values)
                      : new ArrayList<E>()
                   )
                : existing;
    }

    public SortedArrayList(final Collection<? extends E> c){
        this(null, c, null);
    }

    public SortedArrayList(final Collection<? extends E> c,
        final Comparator<? super E> comparator){
        this(null, c, comparator);
    }

    public SortedArrayList(final Comparator<? super E> comparator){
        this(null, null, comparator);
    }

    public SortedArrayList(final int initialCapacity){
        this(new ArrayList<E>(initialCapacity), null, null);
    }

    public SortedArrayList(final int initialCapacity,
        final Comparator<? super E> comparator){
        this(new ArrayList<E>(initialCapacity), null, comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(final E e){
        inner.add(
            Math.abs(
                Collections.binarySearch(inner, e, comparator)
            ) + 1,
            e
        );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int i, E e){throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(final Collection<? extends E> collection){
        return standardAddAll(collection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int i,
        Collection<? extends E> es){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<E> delegate(){ return inner; }

    @Override
    public List<E> subList(final int fromIndex, final int toIndex){
        return new SortedArrayList<E>(
            inner.subList(fromIndex, toIndex),
            null,
            comparator
        );
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(){ return new ListIteratorImpl(0); }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(final int index){
        return new ListIteratorImpl(index);
    }

    @Override
    public E set(int i, E e){ throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }

}
```

Comment: I update my question. If it well be better to move all compare logic to comparator so there will be such consistency.

Comment: I updated my answer. A SortedSet is probably not the right thing for you.

Comment: @seanizer: Very kind of you. +1

Answer (score 2):

`hashcode()` method doesn't guarantee any `less than` or `greater than`. `compare()` and `equals()` should yield the same meaning, but its not necessary, though.

As far as I can understand from your confusing code (no offence intended :)), you want to add duplicates to the `TreeSet`. For that reason you came up with this implementation. Here is the reason, you can't put them in the `TreeSet`, quoting from the docs,

> The behavior of a set is well-defined
>   even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the
>   general contract of the Set interface.

So, you need to do something with yor `equals()` method, so it can never return true whats so ever. The best implementation would be,

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return false;
}
```

By the way, if I am right in my understanding, why not you use `List` instead and sort that.

Answer (score 2):

Beware: even for two Foos `f1`,`f2` with `f1 != f2` you could get `f1.hashCode() == f2.hashCode()`! That means you won't get a stable sorting with your `compare` Method.

Comment: +1 for noticing that the two hashcodes can be the same, -1 because if compare returns 0, the two objects are considered the same (even if equals() returns false).

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule in Java which says that the hash codes of two objects must be different just because they aren't equal (so `o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode()` could return `0` in your case).

Also the behavior of `equals()` *should* be consistent with the results from `compareTo()`. This is not a *must* but if you can't maintain this, it suggests that your design has a big flaw.

I strongly suggest to look at the other fields of the objects and use some of those to extend your comparison so you get a value `!= 0` for objects were `equals() == false`.

Comment: The logic is flawed; it doesn't matter where you put it.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question.
As far as I understand your problem is duplicate elements.

I think that if o1.equals(o2) their hash codes might be equal too. It depends on the implementation of hashCode() in your Foo class. So, I'd suggest you to use System.identityHashCode(x) instead.

Comment: If o1.equals(o2) they can be counted as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Foo` class wich is comparable but want to use a different sorting in a `TreeSet<Foo>` structure. Then your idea is the correct way to do it. Use that constructor to "overrule" the natural sorting of `Foo`.

Comment: I can move this logic to comparator. It would be better? I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
int res = o1.compareTo(o2);

if(res == 0 || !o1.equals(o2)){
    return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();
}
```

Can be problematic, since if 2 objects are equal (i.e. in your `res == 0`) then these 2 objects return the same hashcode. Hashcodes are not unique for every object.

---

**Edit** @Stas, The `System.identityHashCode(Object x);` still won't help you. The reason is described on the javadoc:

> Returns the **same** hash code for the
>   given object as would be returned by
>   the default method `hashCode()`,
>   whether or not the given object's
>   class overrides `hashCode()`. The hash
>   code for the null reference is zero.

Comment: will System.identityHashCode() save me?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, I don't understand it. If there is two different objects their default `hashCode()` would be different with high probability.

Comment: It simply means that `System.identityHashCode()` returns (`x.hashCode()`). So, in your case, it makes no difference whether you use `o1.hashCode()` or `System.identityHashCode(o1)`.

Comment: @Stas, It's preferable that you read Javadocs as sometimes it answers your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no specific expected ordering for any two given elements, but still want to consider them un-equal, then you have to return some specified ordering anyway.

As others have posted, `hashCode()` isn't a good candidate, because the `hashCode()` values of both elements can easily be equal. [`System.identityHashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) might be a better choice, but still isn't perfect, as even `identityHashCode()` doesn't guarantee unique values either

The [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) [`arbitrary()` Ordering](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#arbitrary%28%29) implements a `Comparator` using `System.identityHashCode()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as others said above, hashCode() is not secure to use here. But if you dont care about the ordering of objects that are equal in terms of o1.compareTo(o2) == 0, you could do something like:

```
public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
        int res = o1.compareTo(o2);
        if (res == 0 && !o1.equals(o2)) {
            return -1;
        }
        return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here:

- Hash codes are not generally unique, and in particular `System.identityHashCode` will not be unique on vaguely modern JVMs.
- This is not a question of stability. We are sorting an array, but creating a tree structure. The hash code collisions will cause `compare` to return zero, which for `TreeSet` means one object wins and the other is discarded - it does not degrade to a linked-list (the clue is having "Set" in the name).
- There is generally an integer overflow issue with subtracting one hash code from another. This means the comparison wont be transitive (i.e. it is broken). As luck would have it, on the Sun/Oracle implementation, `System.identityHashCode` always returns positive values. This means that extensive testing will probably not find this particular sort of bug.

I don't believe there is a good way to achieve this using `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Two points may be relevant and these are that the return in one situation is shown as -1 and this depends if a negative value is permitted in the function parameter variable or in the relevant country of use, and also if the method you are using is permitted. There are standard data arranging methods like selector or selection sort and the paper description or code is usually available from a national authority if a copy is not in your workplace. Using comparisons like greater than or less than can speed up the code and avoids the use of a direct comparison for equality by implied dropthrough to later script or code.